# how to Spring integration SftpOutboundGateway setFilter Custom Argument?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

How can I pass a parameter as a filter condition when getting the file list of the SFTP server from MessagingGateway?

My SftpMessageGateway code

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface SftpMessageGateway {
    @Gateway(requestChannel = "getSftpChannel")
    List<SftpFileInfo> getIconListByProductUiId(@Payloads("productUiId") String productUiId);
```

Integration Config

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory() {
    DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
    factory.setHost(host);
    factory.setPort(port);
    factory.setUser(id);
    factory.setPassword(password);
    factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
    return new CachingSessionFactory<>(factory);
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "getSftpChannel")
public MessageHandler getMessageHandler() {
    SftpOutboundGateway outboundGateway = new SftpOutboundGateway(sftpSessionFactory(), "ls", "'" + uploadPath + "'");
    outboundGateway.setOption(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Option.NAME_ONLY);
    outboundGateway.setFilter(new SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter("*alpha*"));
    outboundGateway.setFilter(new SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter("I want get custom argument)); <----
    return outboundGateway;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set only one filter into a gateway, however there is a `CompositeFileListFilter` where you can combine a set of filters, include any custom impl of the `FileListFilter`.

See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/file.html#remote-persistent-flf

Answer (score 0):

You can refer following code snippet for implementing [FileListFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/file/filters/FileListFilter.html). My use case was to fetch most latest file uploaded in SFTP directory.

```
@Component
public class LastModifiedFileFilter implements FileListFilter<LsEntry> {
    
    @Override
    public List<LsEntry> filterFiles(LsEntry[] files) {
        List<LsEntry> result = new ArrayList<LsEntry>();
        Vector<LsEntry> list = new Vector<LsEntry>();
        Collections.addAll(list, files);
        ChannelSftp.LsEntry lastModifiedEntry = Collections.max(list,
                (Comparator.comparingInt(entry -> entry.getAttrs().getMTime())));
        result.add(lastModifiedEntry);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Once you have your own custom filter in place then you need to '[Chain](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/file/filters/ChainFileListFilter.html)' it with your other filters in SftpOutboundGateway object. For your reference, I did it this way

```
    ChainFileListFilter<LsEntry> filterList = new ChainFileListFilter<LsEntry>();
    filterList.addFilter(new SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter("*alpha*"));
    filterList.addFilter(new LastModifiedFileFilter());
    setFilter(filterList);
```

For me, it will now fetch latest file having "alpha" string present in its name. Hope this helps.